# How to stop a list item being displayed at time of creating listview?

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I am working on an application that will display a list of packages with it's name and price. All the data[package's name and price] is coming from server.now i just don't want to display those packages which have price=0...

i have wrote following code into my custom adapter's getview() method...

```
if(packagelist.get(position).getPrice()==0)
                {
                    return null;
                }
```

But returning null in getview() is not working as application crashes. is there any solution?? please help me...

**LogCat Output**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.cakenkeyboard.appoinment, PID: 18099
  java.lang.NullPointerException
      at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2277)
      at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
      at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16514)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5129)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1052)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16514)
      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16514)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5129)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16514)
      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16514)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5129)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
      at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16514)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5129)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16514)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5129)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16514)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5129)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16514)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5129)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2305)
      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16514)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1912)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1109)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5095)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Edit :**
In my application,every packages has two prices. When user selects particular radiobutton, i am updating the whole list through adapter's updateResult() method according to the radiobutton selected.I have stored both price in a single bean class.

This is my bean class which stores the data of particular package...

```
public class PackageData implements Serializable{
private int price1,price2;
private String package_name;
private int id;
private boolean isSelected;

public PackageData(int id, int price1, int price2, String package_name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.price1 = price1;
    this.price2 = price2;
    this.package_name = package_name;
    isSelected = false;
}

public int getId()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public int getPrice1() {
    return price1;
}

public void setPrice1(int price1) {
    this.price1 = price1;
}

public int getPrice2() {
    return price2;
}

public void setPrice2(int price2) {
    this.price2 = price2;
}

public String getPackage_name() {
    return package_name;
}

public void setPackage_name(String package_name) {
    this.package_name = package_name;
}



public void setSelectionFlag(boolean isSelected)
{
    this.isSelected = isSelected;
}

public boolean getSelectionflag()
{
    return this.isSelected;
}}
```

This is my custom adapter....

```
public class PackageRowAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context ctx;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<PackageData> packagelist;
boolean isPrice1;

public PackageRowAdapter(Context ctx, List<PackageData> packagelist)
{
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.packagelist = packagelist;
    isPrice1 = true;

}

public class Viewholder {

     CheckBox chkbox;
     TextView lblprice;

    public Viewholder(View v)
    {
        this.chkbox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.package_row_chkbox);
        this.lblprice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.package_row_price);
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return packagelist.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return packagelist.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

    // getting package data for the row
     PackageData currentPackage = packagelist.get(position);

    TextView lbltitle;
    Viewholder holder = null;


    if (inflater == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_package, parent, false);

            //Binding UI elements with JAVA Objects....
            holder = new Viewholder(convertView);
            lbltitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.package_row_title);

            //setting recieved data into UI elements
            lbltitle.setText(currentPackage.getPackage_name());

            holder.chkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                   set_Checkbox(view);

                }
            });


            convertView.setTag(holder);


        }
    else
        {
            holder = (Viewholder) convertView.getTag();
        }


    holder.chkbox.setChecked(currentPackage.getSelectionflag());

    if(isPrice1)
        {
            holder.lblprice.setText(currentPackage.getPrice1() + " Rs.");
            if(packagelist.get(position).getPrice1()==0)
                {
                    return null;
                }
        }
    else
        {
            holder.lblprice.setText(currentPackage.getPrice2() + " Rs.");
            if(packagelist.get(position).getPrice2()==0)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }


    holder.chkbox.setTag(position);


    return convertView;

}//End of getView()

    public void updateResult(Boolean isPrice1)
    {
        this.isPrice1 = isPrice1;

        //Triggers the list update
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void set_Checkbox(View view)
    {
        CheckBox v = (CheckBox) view;

        int temp_position =(Integer)v.getTag();
        Log.w("Position Value",""+temp_position + "    checked = " + ((CheckBox) view).isChecked());

        PackageData temp_package = packagelist.get(temp_position);

        temp_package.setSelectionFlag(v.isChecked());
    }}
```

Comment: Why is the application crashing? Post your logcat mate

Comment: set visibility gone and visible of your view in getView

Comment: while creating list can you ignore packages whose value is less then zero?

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList packageList;
ArrayList newList;

for(int position=0; position <packageList.size() ; position)
{
if(packagelist.get(position).getPrice()!=0)
newList.add(packagelist.get(position));    
 // new list will not contain PRICE==0

}
```

pass newList to listview instead of packageList. I think it will do the work.

Comment: this will leave a blank view that takes up useless space.

Comment: if i return view...then it will display the view in list. i want to stop the view from being displayed, not to display an empty view......tnx bydway...

Comment: @WadeWilson,yes were right ,try this new code it will work

Answer (score 0):

You should probably store the packages first, then sort out all with 0 and then send them to the list.

Comment: thank bro...i also thought that first, but in my application, every packages has two prices. When user selects particular radiobutton, i am updating the whole list through adapter's updateResult() method....what if the price2 is not 0 while price1 is 0 of that package?? it will not be displayed....that's not the requirement...

Answer (score 0):

Just before Pass to ListView Create One new List and store data only which have value > 0 and then pass that list to listView

Answer (score 0):

```
if(packagelist.get(position).getPrice()!=0)
            {
                textView.setText(""+ packagelist.get(position).getPrice())   // or any code you want when PRICE!=0
            }
else{
 textView.setText(""); // Or any other value you want to display when value is 0
}

try this
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is add the items to the list that you want displayed, then programatically add the views you want displayed at the desired time or you can have a custom adapter with two data sets and a flag that toggles between the two data sets based on what you want to show.

Update:

A another solution would be to add the items you don't want showed unless under special circumstances to the very end of the list, and keep a reference to the index of always displayed items and the display under special circumstances items. Should be noted that this requires special care with keeping the count variables in-sync and has the effect of preventing you from displaying your items in a custom order i.e. anything other than always displayed items and special circumstances item; at least without special sorting logic that is.